# Binding a toggle button to an enum using a value converter

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter

A project I am working on has an enum defined that has only two states. I am using a toggle button to switch the property value.

Using the value converter that I wrote for binding enums to a set of radio buttons does not work since it only changes the value one way due to the `Binding.DoNothing`.

Here is the enum to boolean converter used for the radio buttons that only changes the value in one direction:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value.Equals(parameter);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

As a workaround I modified this specifically for the enum that I am using as shown below by replacing `Binding.DoNothing` with `MyEnum.Off` in the `ConvertBack` method

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : MyEnum.Off;
    }
```

Is there a better way to switch this enum value returned to enable the toggle button to switch the enum to the off state that would be reusable across different Enum types?

Comment: Have you considered the `targetType` in the `ConvertBack(...)` method?

Comment: @Silvermind I'm not quite sure how that would work but it should be possible. Do you have a suggestion for how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest without any type/null/etc checking is the following:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
}
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    return Enum.ToObject(targetType, value);
}
```

`System.Convert.ToBoolean` accepts any **value** type without throwing an exception.

You could als do some additional type checking such as `if (targetType.IsEnum)`, but that's up to you.


According to msdn: [`Enum.ToObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6x6b517(v=vs.110).aspx) only accepts `SByte, Int16, Int32, Int64, Byte, UInt16, UInt32, or UInt64.`, but I suspect it uses `System.Convert` internally so a boolean is also accepted.

Comment: This worked perfectly, boolean is indeed an accepted value into the `Enum.ToObject()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're enum has only 2 states, wouldn't it be simpler to just use a bool? Then you could externalize that to a function that switches the bool to true/false based on its current value

Edit:
After reading the comment left by @Kevin, I realized I misunderstood the original question. The below should hopefully be more in line with what you are asking for. It will take an enum T and iterate through it, returning the `int` index of each next item in the sequence until it reaches the end, where it will return the first item again(0).

```
    private int SwitchEnum<T>(Enum G)
    {                        
        int next = Convert.ToInt32(G) + 1;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), next))
        {
            return next;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

You can call this function as follows:

```
    MyEnum a = new MyEnum(); //Assuming MyEnum is your enum
    a = (MyEnum)SwitchEnum<MyEnum>(a);
```

Comment: Using a bool would get rid of the need for the converter between the UI and the viewModel property but I would still need to convert between the bool and the Enum at some point in the viewModel then to work with the Enum in the rest of the system so that does not remove the need for a converter, it just moves it.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood. See Edits.